# Can someone help me in this place? I get an error when running the command "composer require laravel / socialite" in laravel version 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

-- when I run the command in the command and it gives an error:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/socialite[v5.2.0, ..., 5.x-dev] require illuminate/http ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/http[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/socialite ^5.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v5.2.0, ..., 5.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: try to run `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:-

```
composer require laravel/socialite:^4.4
```

The reason the problem is arising is that they've removed the support for:-

=> Laravel 5.7 support

=> Laravel 5.8 support

=> PHP 7.1 support

from version 5.0 onward.
Do check the [link](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/releases?page=2)